# AVI or any Video file playback in background of opengl

Tags: opengl, video

How I can play video in background of opengl window. Like If I make openGL objects transperent and play video in back of them.
I am making plan to develop opengl application but before want to make sure about this feature as it much needed in validation of real objects vs 3D objects.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in [Lesson 35](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=35) of the excellent NeHe series.